# Is there a way to simplify this exponent?

Tags: exponentiation

I have the exponents $k^4+k^5+k^6$. Is there any way to simplify this into one exponent? I'm trying to find a way to simplify a sequence of increasing exponents into one, but am not sure how. With some guess and checking, I got $k^4+k^5+k^6 \approx k^{6.13368}$, but why does this sequence simplify to approximately $k^{6.13368}$, and how can I simplify other sequences, like $k^6+k^7+k^8+k^9$?

Comment: No.  It doesn’t simplify. Why do you think it does? At best you have Big O approximations.

Comment: For which $k$ did you find this approximation to work? If I plot the two functions, they look nothing alike.

Comment: K = 5 got within 0.7 of the answer, and I asked here because I didn't know if it simplified. I'm not good with exponents, so I thought I would ask here in hopes that there was something I was missing.

Comment: The bigger $k$ gets, the more it's going to look like just the term with the highest exponent. Depending on how good an approximation your need, once$k$ gets bigger than, say, $100$, you can drop all but the highest exponent term.

Comment: You can write it as $(k^7-k^4)/(k-1)$, if that's any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to simplify the expression $P(k)=k^2+k^4+k^6$. However, you can ask a related question: given some particular $k=k_0$, find the exponent $a$ such that

$$
(k_0)^a=P(k_0)
$$

Taking the logarithm of both sides and solving for $a$ gives

$$
a=\frac{\ln{P(k_0)}}{\ln{k_0}}
$$

Substituting $k_0=5$ into the above expression, I find $a=6.133656\dots$, which is in agreement with the exponent you found from trial-end-error.